# What happens if one isn’t sure if ten Jews are watching?

Tags: halacha, maseches-sanhedrin, safek, martyr, chilul-kidush-hashem

The Gemara ([Sanhedrin 74a-b](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=74&format=pdf)) rules that if ten Jews are present when a non-Jew threatens a Jew to perform *any sin* - even to dress like a non-Jew - on pain of death, the Jew is obligated to give up his life.

What if he’s not sure whether there are ten Jews present? Do we say that one is stringent on a Torah law, and so he must give up his life? Or do we say that one is stringent when it comes to life-and-death and he may not give up his life? Perhaps we would apply principles such as “follow the majority” or “kol kavuah” to settle it (or further complicate it)?

I do not ask according to Tosfos (AZ 28a), who rule that in any case one who gives up his life, even if he’s not obligated to, is praiseworthy. I ask only according to the Rambam (Hil. Yesodei HaTorah 5:1) that one is not allowed to give up his life if he’s not obligated to do so, and one who does is considered to have committed suicide.

Comment: @msh210 I don't think this is a duplicate since this question is more specific

Comment: @msh I don’t know that this is a duplicate per se. In that question he asks about a different type of safek - when one’s not sure which posek to hold like. Here the question is when one knows the Halacha, but isn’t sure whether the case in question satisfies the Halachic requirement.

Comment: I think commentators mention not only watching, but also "aware of" the deed.

Comment: @AlBerko That would make sense but I haven’t actually seen such an opinion.

Comment: @DonielF re your comment to me: the _safek_ in _halacha_ is used as an example there (paragraph 2); the question (paragraph 1) is about any _safek_. Or am I misreading it?

Comment: @ba this question is subsumed by the other; we close such things as duplicates. If you want an answer to that question according to the _Rambam_, see https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers

Comment: @msh210 It’s a *very* subtle difference between my question and his first paragraph: he asks about a doubt as to whether one should give up his life or not; I ask about a different doubt, but a nafka minah of that safek is whether one should give up his life. It’s the same distinction between one who’s not sure whether a kli needs tevilah versus one who toveled in a mikvah and later discovered it has less than 40 se’ah. While it’s a very subtle difference in many cases it has a profound distinction in Halacha. B”N I’ll edit it in when I get a chance to look up the sugya in Shav Shmaytsa.

Comment: @msh alternatively ba could just edit the Rambam out of that question